# Type mismatch when trying to search an Array List

Tags: java, arrays, list

Probably be something you can easily spot but I've been stuck with this for a while now. 
I'm trying to search an `ArrayList` for specific text but I'm getting a type mismatch on the search method saying it '`can'not convert from element type Student to String`'. My code is as follows:

College class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList; 
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

public class College {

    private ArrayList<Student> studentList;

    public College()
    {
        studentList = new ArrayList<Student>();           
    }

    public void join(Student newStudent)        
    {
        studentList.add(newStudent);    
    }

    public int numberOfStudents()
    {       
     return studentList.size();       
    }

    public void searchStudents(String searchString) 
    {
        for(String element : studentList){ //Error occurs here
            if(element.contains(searchString)){
                System.out.println(element);
            }
        } 
    }

    public void listmessagesForEach()
    {
        for(String element : studentList){ //Error occurs here
            System.out.println(element);
        }
    }
}
```

Student class:

```
public class Student {

    private String name;
    private int month;
    private int number;
    private int studentId;

    public Student(String name, int month, int number, int studentId)
    {      
        this.name = name;
        this.month = month;
        this.number = number;
        this.studentId = studentId;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public int getMonth()
    {
        return month;
    }

    public int getYear()
    {
        return number;
    }

    public int getStudentID()
    {
        return studentId;
    }

}
```

Testing class:

```
public class Test {


    public static void main(String args[]){


        College myCollege = new College();


        myCollege.join(new Student("Dave Gerry", 2, 1015, 67));
        myCollege.join(new Student("Heidi Pollock", 5, 1017, 57));
        myCollege.join(new Student("Gary Herr", 7, 1013, 47));

        myCollege.numberOfStudents();
        System.out.println("The college has " +
                myCollege.numberOfStudents() +
                " students.");

        String s;
        s = "Herr";
        myCollege.searchStudents(s);

   }
}
```

I need `searchStudents` to identify the text within the list. Error probably also relates to why `listmessages` isn't working to.

This is probably a simple issue just it's hard for contact with my tutor now due to not being able to attend classes at the moment.

Thanks

Comment: please add the entire stack trace you get from the exception in your question

Comment: Clearly `studentList` contains Students not Strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

studentList contains objects of type Student, not strings:

```
public void searchStudents(String searchString) {
    for (Student student : studentList) {
        if (student.getName().contains(searchString)) {
            System.out.println(student.getName());
        }
    } 
}
```

And then you can get the name of the student by using the `getName()` getter. That value is the String which you can check.

And about the listmessages method:

```
public void listmessagesForEach() {
    for (Student student : studentList) {
        System.out.println(student.getName());
    }
}
```

OR:

```
public void listmessagesForEach() {
    for (Student student : studentList){ //Error occurs here
        System.out.println(student);
    }
}
```

but for this last you should add a `toString()` method in your Student class which returns a string with their name or a concatenation of the fields for example.

Comment: Brilliant thanks. For the listmessages method am I right in saying I just need a toString method?

Comment: You should do the same at the for as it's also a collection of Student objects but then, what is `listmessagesForEach()` suposed to do? Print the name of all the students? Or what? I don't see anything else related to message or messages in your classes

Comment: Apologies yes it's meant to print all students but I originally got the hexidecimal output characters

Comment: I've updated the answer, you have different possibilities, if you implement the toString method in your students class you only have to change the type in the for loop

Answer (score 1):

change

```
for(String element : studentList)...
```

to

```
for(Student element : studentList)...
```

and then you need to *decide* what to search for in

```
public void searchStudents(String searchString)
```

should it be .name or .studenId and change the if-statement to match it